# how to write inline matrix in Latex

Tags: latex, mathjax

```
\begin{pmatrix} 2  \\ 4  \\ -2  \end{pmatrix}
```

This is 3*1 vector matrix and i want to write another matrix or *x* and *y* s beside that one.
Is there any method to write matrix **inline** ?

Comment: What happens when you just add another `pmatrix` to the right of the existing one. It should put it right next to it, no?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using in-line delimiters around the math?  E.g.,

```
$\begin{pmatrix} 2  \\ 4  \\ -2  \end{pmatrix}$
```

If you put another matrix inside these delimiters, they will be put in-line next to it.  For instance, see this live example:

```html
<script>
MathJax = {
  tex: {inlineMath: [['$','$']]}
}
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-chtml.js" id="MathJax-script"></script>

This math is in line, $
\begin{pmatrix}
  a & b & c \\
  d & e & f \\
  g & h & i
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 2\\ 4\\ -2 \end{pmatrix}
$, with text following it.
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply put your code inside two dollar signs ($) and it's done.

```
$ \begin{pmatrix} 2  \\ 4  \\ -2  \end{pmatrix} $
```

Note that if you put double dollar signs ($$) it will write the matrix in a new line and then continues the rest of the sentence in the line after that.

```
$$ \begin{pmatrix} 2  \\ 4  \\ -2  \end{pmatrix} $$
```